# Instalar nltk no python 3.6

Tags: nltk

Olá.

Como instalo nltk no python 3.6? Uso o anaconda.

Quando faço:

import nltk

e faço run, não dá erro, mas quando faço nltk. para o autocomplete, não funciona. O módulo está instalado, mas existe alguma incompatibilidade na importação para o código. Li na documentação do nltk que só funciona no python 2.7 e 3.4. Ou seja, uso o 3.6 e reinstalar tudo novamente, mesmo que seja a partir dum arquivo .txt com os pacotes, posso correr o risco de causar outra incompatibilidade, já que estou usando o padnas, numpy, skit-learn, bokhe, matplotlib, etc.

Comment: Sou um leigo na matéria mas:`pip3 nltk` ? o nltk funciona bem python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho antes de tudo reinstalar o módulo do NLTK, nos últimos meses houveram várias mudanças que podem ser interessantes para voce.

Para desinstalar basta  utilizar o comando

```
pip uninstall nltk
```

No console do Anaconda.

Posteriormente aconselho a instalação utilizando o comando:

```
conda install nltk
```

Após obter sucesso na instalação basta abrir o python e digitar a instrução:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

irá abrir a janela de download das bibliotecas, é só selecionar oque precisa.